# Magento 2.3: Using HTML in a Static Block

Tags: blocks, static-block, cms-block

Can I use **HTML** content in a Static Box? If so, please provide the code that I can use in the **Block Content** to identify the code as HTML.
I am trying to use a Widget to insert  HTML content into the Main Content Container of a Category page to use as a **landing page.**

Comment: Please add your Magento version and explain your requirement here.

Comment: Magento 2.3. I think the answer is probably no, but I am new to all of this and working on my own site with a template. I would think that I could add html within a static block - to render a similar page content, but I have been unsuccessful. However, I thought it was worth checking with.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I've added the answer for the same. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

Magento Allows to use HTML content in Static block. Block can be create by Admin from Admin Panel or Programmatically.

I will show you how Admin can add HTML content in Static Block.

> **Step:1** Login into your Magento Admin Penal
>
> **Step:2** After Login Click on **CONTENT-> Blocks**

[image: Going to Static Block Section]

> **Step:3** After Click you will see the Block Grid then Click on **Add New Block**

[image]

> **Step:4** After you have to fill Block Details,the HTML Content and Widget are Add here

[image]

> **Step:5** After save your Block Are show here

[image]

***Note: Every Static Block name have Unique Identifier name so please keep notice that***

Now you want to Add you Static Block in Category page. so you have to Overwrite module-catalog file in your theme.

***app/design/[venore_name] / [Theme_name] / Magento_catalog/layout***

Add this file

***catalog_category_view.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="static_block_identifier_name" >
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">static_block_identifier_name</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

Add here your Static block identifier name shown in Above block Grid. you can also use after and before attribute of this block tag like

you can also need to add same code in ***catalogsearch_result_index.xml.*** at same Path

***Note: you have used default.xml for the layout changes, which will add the layout update in all pages.***

After Done above Process you need to run this command

```
php bin/magento s:up

php bin/magento s:s:d -f

php bin/magento c:c 

php bin/magento c:f
```

After Clear your Browse cache by using **ctrl+shift+delete** and Refresh your Page.

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: if you have any doubt you can ask here